# Rhodes setup and installation for Android in Windows

Tags: android-ndk, rhodes, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to install Rhodes for Android application development. I installed rhodes gem (version 3.2), Android SDK latest release and Android NDK (latest). I run "rhodes-setup" and gave the installation path of Java, Android SDK and NDK. When i try to run "rake run:abdroid" for a sample rhodes applocation, it shows as

"**WARNING!!! Path to Android NDK contain spaces! It will not work because of the G
oogle toolchain restrictions. Move it to another location and reconfigure rhodes.**"

I moved to another location and tried a another version of NDK ( revision 6 and 6b). But still having error. Could please point out what i am doing wrong? 
Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there are no spaces in the path, like the error message suggests.

**Bad NDK Path**

`C:\Program Files (x86)\android-ndk-r4\`

**Good NDK Path**

`C:\source\sdks\android-ndk-r4\`

Update the path to the NDK in the Rhodes build configuration files. Try running "rhodes-setup" again and pointing it to your new NDK path.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your NDK folder to your root folder. I have it like this:

```
C:\android-ndk-r5b
```

Remember to configure rhodes setup after you have made this change and before running your program. You do this by running:

```
$ rhodes-setup
```

on the command prompt while in your app folder.